# How does Appcelerator android module creation work after ADT and Ant support is withdrawn by Google?

Tags: android, appcelerator, titanium-modules, appcelerator-alloy

since google has discontinued support for ADT and Ant, has anybody tried to write android module in Appcelerator? If yes, then how does it work now? Is Ant and ADT required anymore or just having android SDK and NDK  and JDT enough? I'm using Mac, so gpref and Python is already installed. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: I'm getting below error while building the Android module:
could be related to this? https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-23801
I'm using 5.5.1.GA :
[ERROR] :  Failed to run ndk-build
[ERROR] :
[ERROR] :  jni/Android.mk:35: warning: overriding commands for target `/Users/trg/Desktop/Personal/CodePractice/android/build/generated/KrollGeneratedBindings.cpp'
[ERROR] :  jni/Android.mk:35: warning: ignoring old commands for target`/Users/trg/Desktop/Personal/CodePractice/android/build/generated/KrollGeneratedBindings.cpp'
[ERROR] :  jni/Android.mk:35: warning: overriding commands for target `/Users/trg/Desktop/Personal/CodePractice/android/build/generated/KrollGeneratedBindings.cpp'
[ERROR] :  jni/Android.mk:35: warning: ignoring old commands for target`/Users/trg/Desktop/Personal/CodePractice/android/build/generated/KrollGeneratedBindings.cpp'
[ERROR] :  warning: unknown warning option '-Wno-psabi' [-Wunknown-warning-option]
[ERROR] :  In file included from jni/com.android.module.ExampleProxy.cpp:12:
[ERROR] :  /Users/trg/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.0.GA/android/native/include/AndroidUtil.h:57:49: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'long' [-Wformat]
2017-03-06T09:21:07.392Z | ERROR  | An uncaught exception was thrown!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you still can use `ant` to compile modules. But the preferred way is to run `ti build -p android --build-only`